# jenkins and DisplayURLProvider

Tags: jenkins

I have setup jenkins declarative pipeline for our project and also I am using jenkins blue ocean plugin

In github it shows the following url: http://unconfigured-jenkins-location/job/CRM/job/PR-180/1/display/redirect

How can I change the url to a proper one?

I have found that this plugin is responsible https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Display+URL+API+Plugin but I don't understand how to change the url

Can I do it withing the Jenkinsfile? Or in the settings somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed the same recently on one of our Jenkins instances.

Comparing it to one that had the correct URL, I found adding the "jenkinsURL" line to $JENKINS_HOME/jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml and restarting the service would fix it:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration>
  <adminAddress>your-admin-address</adminAddress>
  <jenkinsUrl>https://jenkins.yourcompany.com/</jenkinsUrl>
</jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration>
```

I have no idea why it was missing though. The instance's URL was configured correctly in the config UI.

Comment: Hello
I was stupid enough to add this lines to config.xml and that action killed all the configuration :-) THanks, I will try this now

Comment: maybe you know by any chance, how could I alter the link with github shows as a link to a job? I wanted to navigate users to 'blue' version of jenkins, but the link does not exactly match, because it has `/job/$JOB_NAME` in it, when for blue it should be like `/blue/organizations/jenkins/$JOB_NAME`?

Thanks a lot again

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko DisplayURLProvider is designed to abstract between the old and new interfaces. By default the URL ending in "display/redirect" should go to BlueOcean. To select the old interface you can add -Djenkins.displayurl.provider=org.jenkinsci.plugins.displayurlapi.ClassicDisplayURLProvider.